# $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Bbb P(Y_n >c) =1$ for every $c>0$. Show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Bbb P(X_n+Y_n >c) =1$ or every $c>0$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have trouble in a probability problem. Let {$X_n,n \geq1$} and {$Y_n,n \geq1$} be two sequences of random variables such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}X_n =X$ in distribution for some random variable $X$ with $\Bbb P(|X|<\infty)=1$, and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Bbb P(Y_n >c) =1$ for every $c>0$. Show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Bbb P(X_n+Y_n >c) =1$ or every $c>0$.

I have no clue where to start. Any hints will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given $\varepsilon > 0$, since $X_n \to X$ in distribution and $P(|X| < \infty) = 1$, it can be shown that $\{X_n\}$ is bounded in probability, that is, there exists $M > 0$ such that 
$$P(|X_n| > M) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$
for all $n \geq 1$. Thus for every $c > 0$, by condition, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n > N$， 
$$|P(Y_n > c + M) - 1| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$
then for all $n > N$, we have
\begin{align}
& P(X_n + Y_n \leq c) = P(X_n + Y_n \leq c, |X_n| > M) + P(X_n + Y_n \leq c, |X_n| \leq M)\\
\leq & P(|X_n| > M) + P(Y_n \leq c + M) \\
= & P(|X_n| > M) + 1 - P(Y_n > c + M) \\
< &\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon + \frac{1}{2}\varepsilon = \varepsilon.
\end{align}
which shows that $\lim_{n \to \infty}P(X_n + Y_n \leq c) = 0$ for every $c > 0$, the result follows by taking the complement.